# Is Lua an event-based programming language?

Tags: multithreading, events, node.js, lua, multiprocessing

Is [Lua](http://lua.org) event-based or thread-based?

I've been reading a lot about **Node.js** lately, and it appears that one of the the largest selling points for it is related to it being event-based as opposed to thread-based.  What is Lua?

Comment: I believe Lua leaves that up to the user.

Comment: Why is this question tagged "proc"? Is it the first meaning in the list given at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107791/how-should-the-proc-tag-be-split-up ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not mix terms. **Lua** is a *programming language*. **Node.js** is an evented *library/framework* written using *JavaScript*.

Lua can be (almost) anything you want ;) You can write your code thread-based using libraries like [Lua-Lanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/), or you can create/use event-based libraries. In fact, there is a [Lua port of Node.js](https://github.com/ignacio/LuaNode) in development.

Comment: According to [Tir's homepage](http://tir.mongrel2.org/home), it looks like it supports multiple styles, namely *natural*, *stateless* and *evented*. You should look at the examples to see how they look like.